# Two physical links, different VLANs, no PO. Will PVST shut one link down?

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, spanning-tree, pvst

Two devices - switch A and switch B - two physical links (not bonded/channeled) between them.  First link is configured for say - access VLAN 10, second for access VLAN 20 (but really it could be two trunks with **unique** sets of VLANs).  Switch is running PVST.  Should both links stay up?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both links should stay up. PVST is per VLAN. Each VLAN has its own spanning tree, and it is a spanning tree that decides which interfaces get set to which state for the spanning tree. Each PVST spanning tree VLAN decides for itself if an interface forwards traffic for that VLAN.

STP doesn't actually disable a physical interface, it simply decides if the interface will forward traffic for that spanning tree (each VLAN for PVST). An interface could actually be disabled for one VLAN, and the same interface could be forwarding for a different VLAN.

Comment: Thanks so much for the vote of confidence on this point Ron, answer marked!